# AdMob rewarded video ad only showing in wifi

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

AdMob rewarded video ads only showing when connected to wifi. I have added my device as test device. At the time of developing, device connected to wifi and ads were loading perfectly each time. After published in play store, ads not loading in mobile network. Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Using these dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.0'
```

And initialising it in Application class

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.ad_app_id));
```

In activity

```
mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(getResources().getString(R.string.rewarded_add_exam),
            new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("9438A393A3A730B0EECFA534004F7E6E")
                    .build());

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Test ads are always available. And in real app, `adMob` may not fill ads as ads are not available. Toast error message in published app (for debug only) on `adFailedToLoad` to see whether the ad is feeling or not.

Comment: Test ads are also not loading in mobile data

Comment: Why are you adding `.addTestDevice` in release build. ? Remove that and try to load the app.

Comment: I can continue testing after app published

Comment: There is no need to publish the app to playstore. You can verify whether ads are showing or not before publishing it.

Comment: @Woods AdMob policy does not allow testing with real ads. Having a list of test devices in production code is recommended for testing the app after release.

Comment: @Tomasz yeah. I am doing that.